# Flutter: Use AbsorbPointer without rebuilding entire widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have a Stateful home page which has a list of Stateful widget children. When I click on a child, I'm gonna call its `setState()` to add a CircularProgressIndicator to it. That's all fine and dandy; clicking on a child only rebuilds that child.

However, I also have my home page wrapped inside an `AbsorbPointer`, and I want to set `absorbing = true` when I click on a child widget. The goal is to stop the user from clicking around while the app is doing some async work in the background. The problem now is that if I call `setState()` in the home page to set "absorbing" to true, it will rebuild all of the child widgets.

I could pass some parameters into the child widgets so that only the one I clicked on will have a CircularProgressIndicator, but even then all the other children will still be rebuilt.

I guess this boils down to the fact that I can't call setState() on a parent widget without rebuilding all the children, even though the parameter I pass to that setState() (`absorbing`) has nothing to do with those children.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

```
// home_screen.dart

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "homeScreen";
  final MyUser? user;

  const HomeScreen({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final MyDatabase _db = MyDatabase();
  MyUser? _me;

  int _currentPage = -1;
  bool _isLoading = false;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: _isLoading,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // color: Color(0xFF0d0717),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: Image.asset(
              'assets/background.png',
            ).image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: ...,
          bottomNavigationBar: ...,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 8.0,
                horizontal: 12.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _db.getLiveChannels(),
                    builder: (_, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        // print("Has no data");
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      _channels.addAll(List.generate(
                          snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          (index) => Channel.fromSnapshot(
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index])));
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Now Playing',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                              LiveIndicator(),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 250,
                            child: PageView.builder(
                              physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              controller: PageController(
                                viewportFraction: .9,
                              ),
                              itemCount: _channels.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                Channel channel =
                                    _channels[_channels.length - 1 - index];
                                return ChildWidget(
                                  callback: _callback;
                                  loading: (_isLoading && _currentPage == index),
                                  key: UniqueKey(),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          ...,
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  ...,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _callback(params) async {
    if (_isLoading == false) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
        _currentPage = index;
      });
    }
    someAsyncMethod().then((_) => setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          _currentPage = -1;
        }));
  }

}
```

```
// child_widget.dart

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<void> Function(params) callback;
  final bool loading;

  const ChildWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.callback,
    required this.loading,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  late Future<void> Function(params) callback;

  late bool loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callback = widget.callback;
    loading = widget.loading;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: CustomClickableWidget(
              onPressed: callback,
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      ...,
                      if (loading) ...[
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ...,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ3qMl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The SetState function triggers the Build() function, so all the code present in the Build() function will be executed again. I don't quite see why this is a problem for you ?

On the other hand in your code I see that for your child you have defined a key: UniqueKey (). When the build function will run after SetState (), it will create a new child without keeping the state of the previous child. You shouldn't define the UniqueKey () in your function but rather as an instance variable of your state

```
ChildWidget(callback: _callback;
            loading: (_isLoading && _currentPage == index),
            key: UniqueKey(),
)
```

You should define you key here

```
class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
UniqueKey myKey = UniqueKey();
```

and you function

```
ChildWidget(callback: _callback;
            loading: (_isLoading && _currentPage == index),
            key: myKey,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The thing is I want to somehow rebuild only the child that I click on so that it shows a loading indicator (like in the screenshot), but also change the `absorbing` parameter of the AbsorbPointer in the parent widget. It doesn’t seem like there is a way, so I guess I’m looking for a workaround. My goal is to 1) indicate that I’ve clicked on a particular child, and 2) prevent the user from clicking/scrolling on the app while a background task is running.

Comment: Remove the creation of uniqueKey in the Build () function.  and also I see you initialize the variable "Loading" in your initState of the childwidget.  this variable is therefore only defined once and does not change during the rebuild of your child, the problem may come from there too

Comment: It worked now! I don't know if it's because I removed the uniqueKey as you said, or because there was some issues with my await/async before. But after fixing it I could now call setState() in the child to toggle its loading indicator and call setState() in the parent to toggle its _isLoading variable.